# Create if conditional for return a list with id's my last date in column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df and this df will go receive a date a column 'processing date'. My ask is, how make an filter the values of column 'processing date' with the last day of column

I think to create a conditional if for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I you want to find the rows where `processing_date` is the most recent you can do :

```
df[df.processing_date == df.processing_date.max()]
```